# How to create Boolean indicator matrix in PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, math, matrix

I have the following dataset:

```
        user    artist              sex     country
0        1  red hot chili peppers   f       Germany
1        1  the black dahlia murder f       Germany
2        1  goldfrapp               f       Germany
3        2  dropkick murphys        f       Germany
4        2  le tigre                f       Germany
.
.
289950  19718   bob dylan           f       Canada
289951  19718   pixies              f       Canada
289952  19718   the clash           f       Canada
```

I want to create a Boolean indicator matrix using a dataframe, where there is one row for each user and one column for each artist. For each row(user) if there is artist return 1 else return 0.

Just to mention, there are 1004 unique artists and 15000 unique users—it’s a large data set.

I have created an empty matrix using the following:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=user, columns=artist)
```

I am having difficulty populating the dataframe correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There is a method in pandas called `notnull`

Suppose your dataframe is named df, you should use:

```
df['has_artist'] = df['artist'].notnull()
```

This will add a column of boolean named `has_artist` to your dataframe
If you want to have 0 and 1 do instead:

```
df['has_artist'] = df['artist'].notnull().astype(int)
```

You can also store it in a different variable and not alter your dataframe.